# How to get the average from an array like string in R?

Tags: r, string

I have this string variable.

`x <- "[2,3,3,5]"`

I want to get the average of this. How can I achieve this on R?

Answer (score 5):

In base R:

```r
mean(as.numeric(strsplit(x, '\\D')[[1]]), na.rm = TRUE)
#> [1] 3.25
```

Comment: Doesn't work in a more general case

Answer (score 4):

Looks like **json** format.

```
mean(jsonlite::fromJSON(x))
# [1] 3.25
```

---

*Data:*

```
x <- "[2,3,3,5]"
```

Answer (score 2):

Extract all the digits and then take the mean:

```
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)

str_split(x, ",")[[1]] %>% 
    str_remove_all("\\[|\\]") %>% 
    as.numeric %>% 
    mean
```

```
[1] 3.25
```

Comment: Doesn't work in the general case

Answer (score 1):

We can replace `[]` as `c()` to make a valid expression string in R and then `eval` it, e.g.,

```
> mean(eval(str2lang(paste0("c", chartr("[]", "()", x)))))
[1] 3.25
```

or using `scan` + `substr`

```
> mean(scan(text = substr(x, 2, nchar(x) - 1), sep = ",", quiet = TRUE))
[1] 3.25
```

---

Or, Similarily, we can try `py_eval` to parse the expression in a Python manner

```
> library(reticulate)

> mean(py_eval(x))
[1] 3.25
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also change the "["'s into "("'s and ask for R to interpret the string as a expression with `parse` and `eval`:

```
stringr::str_replace_all(x, c("\\[" = "c\\(", "\\]" = "\\)")) %>% parse(text = .) %>% eval() %>% mean()
```

Comment: However....   `require('fortunes');
fortune('106')`

Answer (score 0):

[this is posted as an answer rather than a comment because I'm demonstrating the value of the incorrect answers]
At least two of the posted answers are incorrect, or at least correct only in the infamous "Microsoft Answer" way.  Consider:

```
x <- "[2,37,1, -45]"
Rgames> mean(as.numeric(strsplit(x, '\\D')[[1]]), na.rm = TRUE)
[1] 21.25
Rgames> mean(as.numeric(str_extract_all(x, "[0-9]")[[1]]))
[1] 3.666667
Rgames> mean(c(2,37,1,-45))
[1] -1.25
```

If you want to extract both positive and negative integers, not to mention integers of absolute magnitude > 10, or floats such as `x <- "[4.8,-65]"` you will need considerably better regex-fu.

As such, Ricard SeC's answer is highly preferable:

```
Rgames> stringr::str_replace_all(x, c("\\[" = "c\\(", "\\]" = "\\)")) %>% parse(text = .) %>% eval() %>% mean()
[1] -1.25
```